# How to create pdf from ASP.Net web Form

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I have developed a ASP.Net application and I have developed a web Form with some entries. Now i want to convert this form into PDF file, is it possible ?

Any good and free library for this ?

Answer (score 2):

To create pdf file you can use [itextsharp](http://itextpdf.com/) or [pdf sharp](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/sharppdf)

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is a good, open source and free option.  After looking around for a solution we ended up exposing wkhtmltopdf as a service because we needed to serve several clients but without maintaining am install for each.   We've subsequently made the API publicly available on http://www.html2pdfrocket.com  and there is no cost if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free libraries such as ITextSharp or for more complex scenarios you can use the server version of TxtControl to generate documents from websites.

TxtControl also offers a OnDemand service for creating documents...

Comment: iTextSharp (and iText, too) are *free for open source software only*. for other uses a commercial license should be purchased.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the Ghostscript library useful http://www.ghostscript.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
     Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
   // Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=hello.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
    string imagepath = Server.MapPath("IMG");
    doc.Open();

    doc.Add(new Paragraph());
    Image gif = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/asd.jpg");
    doc.Add(gif);

    PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);

    table1.WidthPercentage = 90;

    PdfPCell cell11 = new PdfPCell();

    cell11.AddElement(new Paragraph("Receipt ID : " + 124325));

    cell11.AddElement(new Paragraph("Date : " + "25-Feb-2013"));

    cell11.AddElement(new Paragraph("Photo Status : " + "No"));

    cell11.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

    PdfPCell cell12 = new PdfPCell();

    cell12.AddElement(new Paragraph("Transaction ID : " + 4544));

    cell12.AddElement(new Paragraph("Expected Date Of Delivery : " + "25-Feb-2013"));

    cell12.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

    table1.AddCell(cell11);

    table1.AddCell(cell12);

    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(3);



    //One row added

    PdfPCell cell21 = new PdfPCell();

    cell21.AddElement(new Paragraph("Photo Type"));

    PdfPCell cell22 = new PdfPCell();

    cell22.AddElement(new Paragraph("No. of Copies"));

    PdfPCell cell23 = new PdfPCell();

    cell23.AddElement(new Paragraph("Amount"));

    table2.AddCell(cell21);

    table2.AddCell(cell22);

    table2.AddCell(cell23);



    //New Row Added

    PdfPCell cell31 = new PdfPCell();

    cell31.AddElement(new Paragraph("type"));

    cell31.FixedHeight = 300.0f;

    PdfPCell cell32 = new PdfPCell();

    cell32.AddElement(new Paragraph(5));

    cell32.FixedHeight = 300.0f;

    PdfPCell cell33 = new PdfPCell();

    cell33.AddElement(new Paragraph("20.00 *   noOfCopy  = " + (20 * Convert.ToInt32(5)) + ".00"));

    cell33.FixedHeight = 300.0f;



    table2.AddCell(cell31);

    table2.AddCell(cell32);

    table2.AddCell(cell33);



    PdfPCell cell2A = new PdfPCell(table2);

    cell2A.Colspan = 2;

    table1.AddCell(cell2A);

    PdfPCell cell41 = new PdfPCell();

    cell41.AddElement(new Paragraph("Name : " + "fdfgdg"));

    cell41.AddElement(new Paragraph("Advance : " + "245"));

    cell11.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

    PdfPCell cell42 = new PdfPCell();

    cell42.AddElement(new Paragraph("Customer ID : " + 34345));

    cell42.AddElement(new Paragraph("Balance : " + 20545));

    cell42.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

    table1.AddCell(cell41);

    table1.AddCell(cell42);
    doc.Add(table1);

    doc.Close();


    //pdfDoc.Open();
    //htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    //pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(doc);
    Response.End();
```